# Validate Sql Column Names

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 4-5 tables in one database (not SQL Server).

In my UI, users can enter some SQL conditions together with column names in a textbox. I need to verify if the SQL is correct and if these columns exist, and show any errors accordingly. I am using C# for server side.

I have a SQL Server database where our UI stores all the UI related information.

One approach is to create all these tables (just the table structure) in my SQL Server as well and then query a simple select on each table and show the errors or success message(s) accordingly.

So basically I would have the where clause as below or more conditions:

```
where a = b and c in(1,2)
```

As mentioned above I would execute the above where clause against each table I created in SQL Server which would return error if column does not exist.

Is there a better way to approach this? I was thinking in case there is some other way to work without creating so many tables on my SQL Server.

I don't want to hard code these as the structure might change in near future. So looking for some maintainable solution. May be create a single table and store all this information in it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can your application connect directly to the database where these tables live?

Comment: Yes I can directly connect to that but I dont want to query that as its a big database having lots of records. Thats why I want to have it light weight and query our sql db which does not has much data.

Comment: YIKES!!!! This sounds like an incredibly dangerous program. When you start having users enter columns and where predicates in the front end it is a red flag that you are vulnerable to sql injection. Users should NOT be entering column names and such. Additionally your queries should be parameterized, not built up strings using data input from the user.

Comment: You should rethink your application's design completely. Allowing direct access to database elements (through direct user input) is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I can understand the cons but I am handling all others validations,  sql injections etc. Our system is designed as such that I cant use parameterized queries which ofcourse would be the best bet. The solution I require involves users entering columns so looking for some workaround this.

Comment: Crazy. But if you want to validate SQL without damaging DB data, just add programmatically to `where` clause this: `and 1=0`. run the SQL. If it fails to compile, you have mistake somewhere in input.

Comment: Not sure if I am able to clarify above but how would I damage the data where it does not exist in my sql server. I just need to validate the columns via my sql server and I am not actually storing any data. I just have the where conditions from the user input. What I need to do is just execute these conditions against my sql server something like select * from ATable where usercondtions. This would return just an error if there is something wrong with the columns. My only concern was to create multiple table structure so wanted to know in case I could somehow store in one table and query that.

Comment: Because no matter how you slice this your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You claim you are handling it....how? And what kind of insane system prevents using parameterized queries?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server you can query the system object  : 
 information_schema.columns.

That contains a list of all columns for all tables and views.

However, I agree with previous comments - the design you describe is bad bad bad.

Comment: information_schema is somewhat cross-platform, and works on many other database engines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the SQL injection troubles for a second, if the users have control over only the WHERE clause of the query, then you could try and run something like

```
select top 0 * from <tables> where <user-entered-where-clause>
```

and then gracefully handle any errors that are returned.

Comment: But as mentioned above, I might have 4-5 tables. That means I have to table all those in sql server. I was looking for some solution with just a single table

Answer (score 0):

use dmv function in MS sql server to validate the query string. 
assign user string to the variable @Str_query

declare @Str_query as nvarchar(max);
set @Str_query ='SELECT [role_code],[role_description] FROM [dbname].[dbo].[Roles]'
SELECT error_message FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@Str_query, NULL, 0) WHERE column_ordinal = 0

if there is an error message then query string is not valid for execution.